# Loop to revolve planet around sun?

Tags: java, oop

I'm making a solar system simulator and I am having trouble moving the planets, the blue circle is supposed to circle the sun, however when I run my program nothing moves apart from constant flickering.

My code:

```
public class solar
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    while (true) {


    SolarSystem x = new SolarSystem(500,500);
    x.drawSolarObject(0,0,50,"YELLOW");
    x.drawSolarObject(90,45,20,"BLUE");

    x.finishedDrawing();

    }
  }
}
```

I have called methods from a class I am using, for example the drawSolarObject contains distance, angle, diameter, colour.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: I'm confused; what would change between each loop?

Comment: This question related with `javax.swing` or what?

Comment: Where is the movement?  All I see are static objects.  Where is the code that is supposed to make them move?

Comment: the 'angle'-value doesn't change now, does it? It stays for the BLUE object at 45.

Comment: There's not nearly enough detail here for anybody to help you here. What do the arguments to drawSolarObject represent? Why are you destroying the solar system and creating it every time around the loop?

Comment: Are you using some type of framework/library? How do you draw without using a graphics context?

Comment: I'm pretty confused on how to move them, this is the class: http://pastebin.com/CBaZ9LVL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
public class solar
{
  public static void main(String args[])
    int i = 0;
    {
       while (true) {

          SolarSystem x = new SolarSystem(500,500);
          x.drawSolarObject(0,0,50,"YELLOW");
          x.drawSolarObject(90,i,20,"BLUE");

          i++;

          x.finishedDrawing();

    }
  }
}
```

Angle changes by one on each iteration.

Comment: Thanks that works, but for some reason it is still flickering

Comment: @user1902535 The flickering is probably because your graphics context is not double buffered. Invoke `setDoubleBuffered(true)` on your top level component.

Comment: Maybe it's because you are creating a new solar system each time.  What if you create the solar system first outside the loop?  Does that work?